# how to draw simple sparkline graph using react js?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm implementing websocket client-server Application in which websocket server is implemented in the node js that is working fine its waiitng for the client connections on 1234 port.

In the client side I have to implement that in the react js because server is sending messages to the connected clients and based on that messages I have to implement a simple graph using a react sparklines. Please guide me to how I can draw the graph by using this input values coming from websocket?

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var content = document.getElementById('content');
      var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234','security');

      socket.onopen = function () {

      };
      socket.onmessage = function (message) {
         content.innerHTML += message.data +'<br />';
      };
      socket.onerror = function (error) {
         console.log('WebSocket error: ' + error);
      };
    </script>    
 </head>
</html>
```

**App.jsx :**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {


    render() {

  return (
     <div>
        Hello world!!!
     </div>
  );
    }  
}
export default App;
```

**main.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

For now just displaying purpose I'm printing this in onMessage() method. Actually how I can implement this websocket logic and how to draw simple graph?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great explanation on making react component work with Websockets.

https://blog.pusher.com/making-reactjs-realtime-with-websockets/

What you basically do is bind socket.onmessage function inside componentDidMount method of your react component. Then, every time new message arrives, you set the new state of component with setState, which re-renders the component.

Comment: yes...Done with these things...Is there any suitable example for sparkline so that I can understand better how to draw graph? I follow this [ http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47364/ ] link but not understand properly that how to draw graph based on the x axis and y axis contents?

Comment: @kit What kind of data you have? Sparklines typically do not have axes.

Comment: I want date on the x-axis and some random numbers (eg.420) are on y-axis. But got solution actually I have need of GroupBarChart of react-d3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47364/

Since I couldn't find the React Sparkline lib I could link to jsfiddle I have created a mock `<Sparkline>` component which draws a simple graph. But the logic of the code is quite simple:

```
const Graph = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
    return { data : [0.25,1,0.5,0.75,0.25,1,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0.25] }
  },
  componentDidMount(){
    // this is an "echo" websocket service
    this.connection = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
    // listen to onmessage event
    this.connection.onmessage = evt => { 
      // add the new data point to state
        this.setState({
        data : this.state.data.concat([ evt.data ])
      })
    };

    // for testing purposes: sending to the echo service which will send it back back
    setInterval( _ =>{
        this.connection.send( Math.random() )
    }, 1000 )
  },
  render: function() {
    // slice(-10) gives us the ten most recent data points
    return <Sparkline data={ this.state.data.slice(-10) } />;
  }
});
```

Comment: It is really needed for me but when I'm trying this facing **Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle** error , this is because we provided in html file - _<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>_ ...How I can avoid this error n make this app in running condition?